# Proving the existence of a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

Let A be a subset of the positive real numbers. It is required to prove  that there exists a metric space whose non-zero distances are exactly the set A. Any suggestions and hints on how to proceed will be highly appreciated. Please try not to post the exact solution.

Comment: This looks like it can be proven by transfinite induction over $A$. It is enough to show how, having a space with distance set equal to some $A$, build a new space that has a distance space equal to $A \cup \{r\}$ -- this deals with successor step in induction. For the limit step it's looks like it suffices to consider a union.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this thing?

Comment: I’m new to transfinite induction

Comment: If X was a non empty set then, assigning arbitrary values from the set A to pairs of elements won't help since it has to satisfy the triangle inequality. Moreover, the cardinality of the ordered pairs of elements in X has to be equal to the cardinality of A. I simply don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Try thinking about what I wrote in my comment. Let $X$ be a metric space, such that its distances set is equal to $A$. Let $r > 0$ be any real number **not** already in $A$. Can you, starting out from $X$, build a new metric space $X'$, such that the distances set of $X'$ is equal to $A' = A \cup \{ r \} $?

Comment: It is hard to give a useful hint yet not the direct solution. Can you solve the problem for the set say $A=\{1,2\}$?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a hint without disclose the solution.

Consider the example $A=\{1,3\}$. Let $X=A\cup \{0\}$. We need a function $d:X^2\to A$ with following properties

1. $d(x,x) = 0$ for every $x\in X$
2. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for every $x,y\in X$
3. $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for every $x,y,z$

Because of 1. and 2.  we only need to think about $d(0,1), d(0,3), d(1,3)$. Now assign them to $1$ or $3$ such that
$$d(1,3) \le d(0,1) + d(0,3)$$
holds.

Got any idea?